# Commonly used secure login algorithm

Tags: authentication, procedure

I would like to know how does the login procedure work in the Internet sites (e.g. Gmail). I am trying to implement an online application which I want to secure with user authentication.

Could someone give a detailed explanation or point to a relevant site

Comment: Here you go.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-forms-based-website-authentication

Comment: Are you using a web development framework of some sort? If so, it probably has baked-in authentication, which has been tested more thoroughly than code you write yourself. You should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many websites use OpenId to allow users to login. OpenId uses OpenId Providers (such as Google) to login. One big advantage is, you do not have a password for the user stored (so if you get hacked, it can't be leaked). Some info: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid

ASP.Net has the concept of Membershipproviders, which can in turn use many different ways. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx

There are many ways (another may be OAuth) to create a login, I think you can't talk about one single correct way.